# PHP Array pass to function

Tags: php, arrays

I use this function to pass detail through, i am testing it by directly pass through a pre-defined array, however when i access the array within the function everything returns as NULL, not the values i am setting.

```
$this->send_member_email($order=array(
                                    'order_name' => 'D',
                                    'billing_firstname' => 'D',
                                    'billing_lastname' =>  'mcc',
                                    'billing_email' => 'd@test.com',
                                    'billing_address' => 'd',
                                    'billing_city' => 'al',
                                    'billing_postcode' => 'c i',
                            ), "d@test.com", true);
```

I then access it here:

```
$member_data = array(
                    'member_no' => $membership_no,
                    'member_firstname' => $order->billing_firstname,
                    'member_secondname' => $order->billing_lastname,
                    'member_address' => $order->billing_address,
                    'member_city' => $order->billing_city,
                    'member_postcode' => $order->billing_postcode,
                    'member_country' => $order->billing_country,
                    'member_timestamp' => gm_time('datetime'),
            );
```

Am i formatting the array wrong or is it an overlook on my behalf. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

this is what it logs as values into db:

```
VALUES ('fd310a396f8c9', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2016-06-08 11:10:36')
```

Comment: Use `$order['billing_firstname']` Its array not object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$member_data = array(
                'member_no' => $membership_no,
                'member_firstname' => $order['billing_firstname'],
                'member_secondname' => $order['billing_lastname'],
                'member_address' => $order['billing_address'],
                'member_city' => $order['billing_city'],
                'member_postcode' => $order['billing_postcode'],
                'member_country' => $order['billing_country'],
                'member_timestamp' => gm_time('datetime'),
        );
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.

Comment: glad to help you
please accept answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `$order['billing_firstname']`